# Laravel 5.5: Whopps only display some of the details

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, whoops

I'm using laravel 5.5 and i've noticed that at some scenarios whoops will only show some details:
[image: screenshot]

Most of the text is missing, any ideas what is going on?

Comment: That's because that's all info  it can provide about the error

Comment: @MahdiYounesi no, to me it looks like the text is the same color as the background. Maybe a browser extension

Comment: Try highlighting all text and see if you can read it then? I think this is a browser issue not backend/whoops

Comment: @andrewtweber of course i already checked that via the inspector, there is nothing there at the html